# how to correctly customize section and equation using cleveref

Tags: cleveref

I want to be able to change the standard way cleveref package makes reference to a section, or an equation. I thought the commands

```
\crefformat{section}{\S#2#1#3}
\crefformat{equation}{(#2#1#3)}
```

would work fine; actually, they seem to work ok, also with capitalize, etc, except when I refer to multiple stuff, e.g. `\cref{sec1,sec2}`, in which case it still uses the default 'sections', or 'eqs.': What is then the correct way to customize cref behavior, so that for multiple sections I get something like §§1,2 and for equations I get (4),(5) or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your preamble:

```
\crefmultiformat{section}{\S\S\,#2#1#3}%
{ and~(#2#1#3)}{, #2#1#3}{ and~#2#1#3}
\crefmultiformat{equation}{ (#2#1#3)}%
{ and~(#2#1#3)}{, (#2#1#3)}{ and~(#2#1#3)}
```

Comment: actually, the complete set of commands should specify \crefformat \crefrange \crefmultiformat \crefrangemultiformat, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. I supposed you would have a look at the doc and would find it by yourself. Apparently, 'twas a good bet (or a good bait? :o))